# Unity erase parts of an image

Tags: graphics, unity-game-engine

Good day, I was wondering on how can I implement an effect like the ones on the sweepstakes where you scratch the grey part and reveal a number underneath it. I was wondering how can I implement that in unity, I don't have any clue where to start, thanks in advance.

the idea is, I have 2 overlapping objects, A and B, whereas when I click on a part of B it will be removed and will show a part of A, both A and B are sprite images though

Comment: One approach you might take if you're determined to keep both A and B as sprites, is to use pixel colour replacement on B whenever it is clicked. So when you click on B, the pixels of B around your cursor are coloured a transparent colour (alpha = 0), revealing that portion of A underneath. Take a look at [this Unity question](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/best-easiest-way-to-change-color-of-certain-pixels-in-a-single-sprite.223030/) for ideas on implementation.

Comment: Thanks will look into this, I get the idea :)

Comment: how can I get the texture of my gameobject?

Comment: hmmm.. I get it now, with your reference. I think when every time I brush through B I have to keep on replacing the old sprite to the new sprite with the alphas changed to zero. Is there anyway I acn directly change the sprite without replacing it?

Comment: Yes - the alternative is to modify the texture directly. Note however, that this will apply the change permanently (even after restarting the scene), as it alters the file itself. Take a look at how the original implementation went in [this Unity question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/622444/setpixel-on-a-sprite-texture-without-changing-it-g.html).

Comment: Would you recommend this for mobile? I feel that the "for loop" is too taxing for the memory, w/c can result to make the app crash

Comment: As long as the loop isn't too lengthy, I wouldn't expect it to cause major problems. (Eg. Don't loop through all of pixels of a 640 x 480 texture and then use nested loops to perform operations on all of them. =P) There will be some performance impact (as with any code), but you'll have to test it on the target hardware to see if it's negligible. You could implement some form of rate-limiting or queuing up spots to erase if you're really worried it will slow down other parts of the app, but then the interaction will definitely feel sluggish.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really related to Unity as such. This relates more to a general technical solution for a visual representation you would like to do.

So, let's skip the Unity part.

But even then the question is very general and hard to respond to. There are many ways to achieve this, depending on the result you want.

You could apply a quad object, with a grey texture on top of whatever number box you have and then either use shaders to show the number as you "scratch it". Or you could remove the grey square when clicking it (different behaviour). Or you could do the old school approach and replace pixels, as you "scratch" the box.

Only to mention a few ideas.

But still, the question is very general and hard to answer as it pertains to a general idea, and not so much a concrete question.

Comment: Good day, the idea is, I have 2 overlapping objects, A and B, whereas when I click on a part of B it will be removed and will show a part of A, both A and B are sprite images though

Answer (score 0):

Look into how to build Fog of war shader. I would achieve this by rendering A and B with two separate cameras then as you scratch it off it would reveal B in the scratched area.

Comment: well that's the idea that I was thinking, I just don't know where to start, what to use, or etc.

Comment: Would you recommend static and dynamic fog of war for mobile devices?

Comment: dynamic shader based. search for Unity fog of war and there is a pretty good tutorial on getting set up.